# UITableView pull to refresh and pagination using willDisplay

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination, pull-to-refresh

It's my 3rd day and after reading almost over scores of tuts I couldn't figure out how to implement pagination in UITableview using `willDisplay` method. I'm trying to mimic iMessages pull to paginate feature.

My code below goes into infinite loop when pulled to refresh the first time.

Can anyone look into the code and suggest a way to fix infinite loading?

Tx in advance.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 && !self.isLoading {

        self.isLoading = true

        fetchClientsMessages(page: self.currentPage, completed: {

            if self.currentPage == 0 {
                self.messageArray.removeAll()
            }

            self.messageArray.append(contentsOf: self.clientChatMessages!.messages!)

            // Sort message by ID so that latest message appear at the bottom.
            self.messageArray = self.messageArray.sorted(by: {$0.id! < $1.id!})

            self.messagesTable.reloadData()

            // Scroll to the top
            self.messagesTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)

            self.lastPage = self.currentPage

            self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
            self.isLoading = false
        })

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In first load the code inside if will run, then in its callback you do

```
self.messagesTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
self.isLoading = false
```

which will trigger `willDisplay` again as `indexPath = 0` and `isLoading = false` => infinite loading , what you want is to slightly scroll down the table to indicate data loaded, then leave the user scroll up until hitting index = 0 again

Comment: I've commented //self.messagesTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true) it still goes into infinite loop, so this doesn't seem to cause any issue. There is something else missing so stop infinite loading.

Comment: can you use insertRows instead of    self.messagesTable.reloadData()

Comment: I'll try, looks like another few days of time to figure out that insertRows thingy now.

Answer (score 0):

You should move scrolling and `reloadData` to the top last in the `fetchClientMessages` method

```
    fetchClientsMessages(page: self.currentPage, completed: {

        if self.currentPage == 0 {
            self.messageArray.removeAll()
        }

        self.messageArray.append(contentsOf: self.clientChatMessages!.messages!)

        // Sort message by ID so that latest message appear at the bottom.
        self.messageArray = self.messageArray.sorted(by: {$0.id! < $1.id!})

        self.lastPage = self.currentPage

        self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
        self.isLoading = false

        self.messagesTable.reloadData()

        // Scroll to the top
        self.messagesTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
    })
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Tx for suggestion but it doesn't work, it still goes into infinite loop.

Comment: As I've said earlier even commenting out scrolling to top line doesn't help. It still goes into infinite loop.

Comment: @DaveMS I have updated my answer. try also putting the `reloadData` after the `isLoading = false`. This also causes the `willDisplay` method to be called again. I missed it in my first version

Comment: Didn't' help, same result it's still going in infinite loop.

Comment: do you set `self.isLoading = false` in any other place?

Comment: var isLoading = false declared in the beginning of VC class. It's not set anywhere else.